# Creating a countdown using sox, struggling with combining syntax

Tags: mixing

I have 5 files of speech (simply "five", "four" etc) each less than 1 second long, that I'd like to play along side a series of tones in order to create a countdown, using sox, not ffmpeg.

Playing "five" then tones is easy enough:

```
play \
-r 22050 -t aiff five.aiff \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -p synth 1 square E5"
```

Playing "five" stereo left with a tone stereo right:

```
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 Five.aiff \
"|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" \
remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2
```

However, trying to combine these two ideas, that of each speech accompanying a tone and then making these sequential ends up in various kinds of errors or process hangs, or a mess of overlapped tones. For example, by using sequential shell commands via `&&` but then I lose the ability (as far as I know) to output a single file without using temp files and the like:

```
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 Five.aiff "|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2 &&
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 four.aiff "|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2 &&
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 three.aiff "|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2 &&
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 two.aiff "|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2 &&
play --combine merge -r 22050 -t aiff -c 1 one.aiff "|sox -n --rate 22050 -c 1 -p synth 0.5 square E4 pad 0 0.5" remix 1,2v0.2 1v0.2,2 && play -n --rate 22050 synth 1 square E5
```

I've tried lots of variations from the man page but I'll spare you them all, I just don't know what to try next.

Any help or insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Workaround: you can extract the words audio and the tone as separate audio files (preferably .wav for reasons of quality), then arrange these pieces in an audio tool like Audacity and extract the arranged project as an audio file (with your preferred encoding) again.

Comment: This is not so much a sound design question as it is a request for SoX support, which is probably best obtained from the [SoX Mailing List](https://sourceforge.net/p/sox/mailman/).

Comment: @DataProcessing Fair comment, thanks for the link.